# Передовик — чего или в чем?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, выбор-варианта

Передовик эфиромасличной отрасли. Можно так сказать?

Answer (score 1):

С родительным падежом (чего?) никаких проблем нет.
В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[ПЕРЕДОВИ́К](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Peredovik-22453.html), -а́; *м.* В СССР: тот, кто опережал других в работе, добивался наилучших результатов. ***Передовики производства.** Ходить в передовиках. Встреча передовиков. Выбиться в передовики.*

Отрасль — это отдельная область хозяйственной деятельности, науки, производства, поэтому, думаю, можно сказать "передовик отрасли" (и уже не столь важно, какой именно).
Слово "передовик" в этом значении используется до сих пор, поэтому в примерах я указала даты.

*Прежде — **передовик отрасли**, сегодня предприятие на грани банкротства* (о Мурманском рыбокомбинате; 2014 г.).
***Передовик отрасли**, отдавший работе на железнодорожном транспорте 21 год, рационализатор, обладатель званий...* (о человеке — работнике Белгородской дистанции пути; 2018 г.).

Предложный падеж (в чём?) тоже употребляется, правда, нечасто.

И то правда: СССР шагал передовиком в атомной и космической науках, в спорте, нередко и в искусстве. [Сергей Залыгин. Предисловие // «Новый Мир», 1998]
*Это передовик в производстве хлебопекарного оборудования с более чем двадцатилетней историей* (о ЗАО "Восход", Саратов).